# nodejs: error cannot get /

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs

[image: Screenshot de mi problema con nodejs]

en el index.js estoy requiriendo el archivo que se ve en el screen (server.js) pero en el navegador me aparece este error, que puedo hacer, estoy empezando con nodejs

Comment: Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de texto en formato de imagen pues se hace difícil su lectura, en cambio puedes editar y agregarlo como texto

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda no publicar tu código en imágenes ya es es muy difícil leerlo o duplicarlo
No es un erro como tal, es debido a que no has creado rutas.

esta seria la ruta '/'

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   return res.send('Hola Mundo')
});

module.export = app;
```